# Comultiplication in Convolution algebra: Where is the mistake?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group and $C(G)$ its convolution Hopf algebra. It is known that the characters $\widehat{G}$ form an orthogonal basis in $C(G)$ and $\sum_{\chi \in \widehat{G}}\, \chi = |G|\cdot \delta_e$, where the delta function $\delta_e$ is the unit in $C(G)$. Moreover, the characters are grouplike elements. If this is all true, what am I doing wrong in the following chain of equations:$$
\sum_{\chi} \chi \otimes \chi =\sum_\chi \Delta(\chi) = \Delta\left(\sum_\chi \chi\right) =|G|\Delta(\delta_e)=|G|\delta_e \otimes \delta_e=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\chi,\chi'} \chi\otimes \chi',$$
which can't be since $\chi\otimes \chi'$ form a basis of $C(G)\otimes C(G)$?!

Comment: what is $\Delta$ ?

Comment: the comultiplication, defined by precomposition with the group multiplication and using the isomorphism $C(G \times G) \cong C(G)\otimes C(G)$..

Comment: And $\chi = \sum_{g \in \chi} \chi(g) \delta_g$ so that $\sum_\chi \chi \otimes \chi = \sum_\chi \sum_g\sum_{g'}  \chi(g)\chi(g') \delta_g \otimes \delta_{g'}=\sum_g\sum_{g'}  \delta_g \otimes \delta_{g'} \sum_\chi \chi(gg')$ 
$=\sum_g\sum_{g'}  (\delta_g \otimes \delta_{g'}) |G|1_{g g'=e}=|G|\sum_g  \delta_g \otimes \delta_{g^{-1}}$

Comment: yes, but I wanted to avoid using the delta-basis..

Comment: You can set $\Delta (\delta_g) = \delta_g \otimes \delta_g$ but $ \delta_g \otimes \delta_g+ \delta_{g'} \otimes \delta_{g'}=\Delta(\delta_g)+\Delta(\delta_{g'}  ) =\Delta(\delta_g+\delta_{g'}  ) = (\delta_g+\delta_{g'}) \otimes (\delta_g+\delta_{g'})$ isn't correct

Comment: ahh, I read somewhere that the characters are the grouplikes (i.e. $\Delta (\chi)=\chi \otimes \chi$), but this can't be true since $\Delta(\delta_e)=\delta_e\otimes \delta_e$ must be fulfilled.. you're probably right that this holds for all $g$.. thanks!

Comment: Now I didn't mention the convolution anywhere, so it is very possible that $\Delta(\chi)$ behave nicely for some convolution identities

Comment: Is your group $G$ abelian? Otherwise, what you are claiming (about grouplikeness of characters in particular) sounds very wrong...

Comment: i think, even if $G$ is abelian it's wrong.. it should be $\Delta(\chi)=\sum_{\chi'}\chi' \otimes \chi \bar{\chi}'$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake lies in your assertion that the characters are grouplikes. In fact, if one considers the characters to be grouplikes, applying the comultiplication map $\Delta:C(G)\rightarrow C(G)\otimes C(G)$, to both sides of the relation 
$$
\sum_{\chi \in \widehat{G}}\, \chi = |G|\cdot \delta_e
$$
easily yields a contradiction.